# BackgroundWorker ignores Impersonation

Tags: c#, windows, backgroundworker, impersonation

In my C# application, I use `Impersonation` to extend access rights of users. For convenience, I just added a `public static Impersonation` object, which is initialized at App startup.

The code for `Impersonation` is from [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/5710991).
Executing any code in the app so far works fine:

```
someCodeThatNeedsImpersonation(); // Fine
somethingElse();
```

I now want to move code into a `BackgroundWorker`:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (s, a) =>
{
    someCodeThatNeedsImpersonation(); // fails to "see" impersonation
}
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) =>
{
    somethingElse();
}
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

This fails, because apparently the `Impersonation` handle that was initialized in the main thread is not used in the `BackgroundWorker`.

A quick fix, of course, is

```
bw.DoWork += (s, a) =>
{
    using ( new Impersonation(...) )
    {
        someCodeThatNeedsImpersonation(); // works, because of bw's own impersonation
    }
}
```

but I would prefer a solution that doesn't need a new Impersonation handle in every BackgroundWorker (because I will surely forget one). Is there a way to share the `static Impersonation` object of the main thread?

Comment: This is about ASP .NET, but the reason and solutions are the same: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/04/22/making-an-asynchronous-call-using-the-impersonation-identity.aspx

Comment: Also this may help: http://blog.iamandycohen.com/2012/09/17/await-async-mvc-and-impersonation/

Comment: @Dennis thanks for the links. Method 2 of the first link (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/04/22/making-an-asynchronous-call-using-the-impersonation-identity.aspx) works flawlessly. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: Well, there are no my investments in the answer, so, feel free to post answer yourself. Besides, the question as it stated, is a ground for wide discussion - since this is desktop application (I assume it from using `BackgroundWorker`), it's a big question, why do you need so many places to impersonate. So, the solution you accepted doesn't look good for me, because, IMO, it hides real design problems.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, the impersonation token is maintained for each thread separately, and isn't inherited when you create new threads.

The way to go is by impersonating just the code paths that need it, as you already showed with your `using(...)`. The only difference, I'd say, was that instead of issuing `.DoWork +=  { new Impersonation(...) }` I would do something like this:

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += Impersonated(TOKEN, (s, a) => { /* code */ });
```

Another approach, given that `BackgroundWorker` isn't sealed, and its `OnDoWork()` method is protected, would be to inherit the class and override `OnDoWork()` to impersonate. Then, you could do:

```
var bw = new ImpersonatingBackgroundWorker(...)
```

Comment: I fully agree with "impersonation only where you need it", but that's how projects grow..

Comment: Yeah, well, you can use the lengthier impersonation but still reduce duplication, like in my example. The other thing you can do, noticing `BackgroundWorker` isn't a sealed class, and `OnDoWork()` is protected, is to inherit and override `OnDoWork()` to impersonate. Then just do `var bw = new ImpersonatingBackgroundWorker(...)`. But I personally like the example I gave--without inheritance--better.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on [blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/04/22/making-an-asynchronous-call-using-the-impersonation-identity.aspx), adding the following snippet to the `App.config` file is sufficient for `Impersonation` to cross thread bounds.

```
<configuration>
 <runtime>
   <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>
   <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="false"/>
 </runtime>
</configuration>
```

However, a best practice solution would only use impersonation where it is actually needed, rather than globally.